# Kafka TimeoutException: Topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I'm trying out with some Kafka basics and following examples at https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart. After starting zookeepier and kafka, I tried producing and consuming with included kafka shell scripts and it all worked without issue.
When I try to produce message from simple scala application then I get following error `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic quickstart-events not present in metadata after 60000 ms.`
I ensured the topic has been created and can telnet to localhost:9092 as well.

Here's the code I'm using for producer:

```
val props = new Properties()
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "test")
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringSerializer].getName)
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringSerializer].getName)

val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String]("quickstart-events", "1", "some event")).get()
```

Running this on mac, above code is part of a test case executed in IntelliJ.

Comment: Are you sure the topic was created?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, and I can produce and consume from that topic with included shell scripts.

Comment: Where are you running this code? From an IDE? As a JAR? From Scala REPL?

Comment: If you're running windows and started Kafka in WSL2, then you won't be able to directly connect to it from Windows environment/code, for example, but CLI tools within WSL2 terminal will be able to

Comment: @OneCricketeer updated question content "Running this on mac, above code is part of a test case executed in IntelliJ."

Comment: Can you please show output of `kafka-topics --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer `~/kafka_2.13-3.2.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
__consumer_offsets
quickstart-events
transactionApproved`

Comment: I'm not really sure. My only thought would be if Intellij is trying to run tests in some container/remote environment, or if it's in "offline mode"... If you really want to do unit tests against Kafka, though, there are alternative libraries that'll manage the broker and topic lifecycles during tests

Comment: @OneCricketeer main reason I used test here was to quickly verify producer works, also tried in repl, same timeout error. Will try to build a jar and see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 3):

Solved. I used `kafka-clients` library version `2.6.0` and running kafka server version `3.2.0`. Matching version of the library fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes. Newer clients can connect to old brokers. Using older versions to connect to new brokers should be avoided

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem as well, the version is correct for me. 
I figure out it's the lack of sasl certification.
try:

```
// set SASL configuration here
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, “SASL_PLAINTEXT”);
props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, “PLAIN”);
props.put(“sasl.jaas.config”,
“org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\”alice\” password=\”123456\”;”);
```